# RapidMiner TimeSeries prediction

Tags: time-series, prediction, forecasting, rapidminer, windowing

I am working with the RapidMiner Windowing operator, in order to forecast the value of a company's revenue in the future.

The dataset contains a value per month, so that I used a window size of 12. However, I am not able to know which the values are going to be for 3 months in advance. I thought the "horizon" parameter was the one to choose how many time-units in advance to forecast, but this didn't work.

Dataset example:

```
date    value
2016-01-01  5,0
2016-02-01  15,0
2016-03-01  10,0
2016-04-01  20,0
2016-05-01  15,0
2016-06-01  25,0
2016-07-01  20,0
2016-08-01  30,0
2016-09-01  25,0
2016-10-01  35,0
```

What should I do in order to forecast some values in the future?? Let's say values for 2016-11-01 and 2016-12-01 ??

As @awchisholm proposed, here it is the two windowing process. However, I don't know the parameters needed in order to forecast this future months' values.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><process version="7.1.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.1.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_excel" compatibility="7.1.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Read Excel" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="excel_file" value="D:\Users\iesnaola\Desktop\prueba.xlsx"/>
        <parameter key="imported_cell_range" value="A1:B11"/>
        <parameter key="first_row_as_names" value="false"/>
        <list key="annotations">
          <parameter key="0" value="Name"/>
        </list>
        <list key="data_set_meta_data_information"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="7.1.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Set Role" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="date"/>
        <parameter key="target_role" value="id"/>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="series:windowing" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Windowing for Training" width="90" x="313" y="34">
        <parameter key="window_size" value="5"/>
        <parameter key="create_label" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="label_attribute" value="value"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="series:windowing" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Windowing for Test (2)" width="90" x="313" y="136">
        <parameter key="window_size" value="5"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read Excel" from_port="output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Windowing for Training" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Windowing for Training" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Windowing for Training" from_port="original" to_op="Windowing for Test (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Windowing for Test (2)" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 2"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to know without your data, so here's a reproducible example process that shows windowing as well as the use of the horizon parameter. This works if the attribute to be used as a label is already a label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="45" y="34">
    <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="45" y="136">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
    <parameter key="attributes" value="id"/>
    <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_copy" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Copy" width="90" x="45" y="238">
    <parameter key="attribute_name" value="id"/>
    <parameter key="new_name" value="idcopy"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Set Role" width="90" x="246" y="34">
    <parameter key="attribute_name" value="id"/>
    <list key="set_additional_roles">
      <parameter key="idcopy" value="label"/>
    </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="series:windowing" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Windowing" width="90" x="380" y="34">
    <parameter key="window_size" value="5"/>
    <parameter key="create_label" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="label_attribute" value="idcopy"/>
    <parameter key="horizon" value="5"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate Copy" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Copy" from_port="example set output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Windowing" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Windowing" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Windowing" from_port="original" to_port="result 2"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Hope that helps as a start.

Comment: Hmmm that's exactly what I was talking about. Your dataset has 150 rows (in RapidMiner they are called examples), and your windowing, only "predicts" until the 150th value. What could I do in order to forecast the 151th, 152th and 153th values?? Let's say my dataset is something like `January = 10; February = 20; March = 15; April = 25` and I want to forecast values for May, June and July. How dould I do this??

Comment: The result consists of 141 examples. The last one corresponds to the examples for 141 to 145 inclusive pivoted into attributes and the label is for id150 which is at least 5 beyond the latest attribute.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I am not understanding you (maybe the dataset is not the easiest one to understand). Let's just try it with a dataset like the one I am writing here: `date value
2016-01-01 00:00:00 5,0
2016-02-01 00:00:00 15,0
2016-03-01 00:00:00 10,0
2016-04-01 00:00:00 20,0
2016-05-01 00:00:00 15,0
2016-06-01 00:00:00 25,0
2016-07-01 00:00:00 20,0
2016-08-01 00:00:00 30,0
2016-09-01 00:00:00 25,0
2016-10-01 00:00:00 35,0` Now with the process you proposed, could I forecast values for 2016-11-01 and 2016-11-02 for example??

Comment: To be clear, you want to predict the first and second of November based on data for the first day of each preceding month? I think that will be tough because there is no data for any second days in the preceding months.

Comment: My bad. I would like to predict November and December. Just using the idea of "learning" from the previous months, in order to forecast the future.

Comment: So you want to predict November from October and all previous months and additionally predict December from October and all previous months. Why not run the`Windowing` operator twice with different window settings?

Comment: I think that could be a good option. Could you please help me giving some hint on which parameters should I use to achieve this?? (I put the XML on my first question)

Comment: Have you tried building any models? This is what you have to do to make predictions. The `Windowing` operator by itself does not do this.

Comment: Yes I have (I didn't put it in the XML to keep it as simple as possible, but I also use other preprocessing operators). The output of the Windowing is the input to my algorithm (let's say Linear Regression), and this gives me my model. What brings me to the same point: I have a dataset from January to October, I have a model trained with that data...and now I want to use that model to forecast the next X months.

Comment: My thought was to create multiple labels then you can use `Loop Labels` to iterate over them. There is help associated with that operator that shows a simple example.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen a example of a process using the Loop, and renaming of the Windowing... seems quite manual and not very straightforward... I was wondering if RapidMiner had another easier way of doing this. Many thanks for your time and effort in helping me. I really appreciate it :)